# Problems with variable referenced before assignment when using os.path.walk

Tags: python, function, global-variables, variable-assignment

OK. I have some background in Matlab and I'm now switching to Python.
I have this bit of code under Pythnon 2.6.5 on 64-bit Linux which scrolls through directories, finds files named 'GeneralData.dat', retrieves some data from them and stitches them into a new data set:

```
import pylab as p
import os, re
import linecache as ln

def LoadGenomeMeanSize(arg, dirname, files):
        for file in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(dirname, file)
            if filepath == os.path.join(dirname,'GeneralData.dat'):
                data = p.genfromtxt(filepath)
                if data[-1,4] != 0.0: # checking if data set is OK 
                    data_chopped = data[1000:-1,:] # removing some of data
                    Grand_mean = data_chopped[:,2].mean()
                    Grand_STD = p.sqrt((sum(data_chopped[:,4]*data_chopped[:,3]**2) + sum((data_chopped[:,2]-Grand_mean)**2))/sum(data_chopped[:,4]))
                else:
                    break
            if filepath == os.path.join(dirname,'ModelParams.dat'):
                l = re.split(" ", ln.getline(filepath, 6))
                turb_param = float(l[2])                
                arg.append((Grand_mean, Grand_STD, turb_param))

GrandMeansData = []
os.path.walk(os.getcwd(), LoadGenomeMeanSize, GrandMeansData)
GrandMeansData = sorted(GrandMeansData, key=lambda data_sort: data_sort[2])

TheMeans = p.zeros((len(GrandMeansData), 3 ))
i = 0
for item in GrandMeansData:
    TheMeans[i,0] = item[0]
    TheMeans[i,1] = item[1]
    TheMeans[i,2] = item[2]
    i += 1

print TheMeans # just checking...
# later do some computation on TheMeans in NumPy
```

And it throws me this (though I would swear it was working a month ego):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/User/01_PyScripts/TESTtest.py", line 29, in <module>
    os.path.walk(os.getcwd(), LoadGenomeMeanSize, GrandMeansData)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/posixpath.py", line 233, in walk
    walk(name, func, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/posixpath.py", line 225, in walk
    func(arg, top, names)
  File "/home/User/01_PyScripts/TESTtest.py", line 26, in LoadGenomeMeanSize
    arg.append((Grand_mean, Grand_STD, turb_param))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Grand_mean' referenced before assignment
```

All right... so I went and did some reading and came up with this global variable:

```
import pylab as p
import os, re
import linecache as ln

Grand_mean = p.nan
Grand_STD = p.nan
def LoadGenomeMeanSize(arg, dirname, files):
        for file in files:
            global Grand_mean
            global Grand_STD
            filepath = os.path.join(dirname, file)
            if filepath == os.path.join(dirname,'GeneralData.dat'):
                data = p.genfromtxt(filepath)
                if data[-1,4] != 0.0: # checking if data set is OK 
                    data_chopped = data[1000:-1,:]  # removing some of data
                    Grand_mean = data_chopped[:,2].mean()
                    Grand_STD = p.sqrt((sum(data_chopped[:,4]*data_chopped[:,3]**2) + sum((data_chopped[:,2]-Grand_mean)**2))/sum(data_chopped[:,4]))
                else:
                    break
            if filepath == os.path.join(dirname,'ModelParams.dat'):
                l = re.split(" ", ln.getline(filepath, 6))
                turb_param = float(l[2])                
                arg.append((Grand_mean, Grand_STD, turb_param))

GrandMeansData = []
os.path.walk(os.getcwd(), LoadGenomeMeanSize, GrandMeansData)
GrandMeansData = sorted(GrandMeansData, key=lambda data_sort: data_sort[2])

TheMeans = p.zeros((len(GrandMeansData), 3 ))
i = 0
for item in GrandMeansData:
    TheMeans[i,0] = item[0]
    TheMeans[i,1] = item[1]
    TheMeans[i,2] = item[2]
    i += 1

print TheMeans # just checking...
# later do some computation on TheMeans in NumPy
```

It does not give error massages. Even gives a file with data... but data are bloody wrong! I checked some of them manually by running commands:

```
import pylab as p
data = p.genfromtxt(filepath)
data_chopped = data[1000:-1,:]
Grand_mean = data_chopped[:,2].mean()
Grand_STD = p.sqrt((sum(data_chopped[:,4]*data_chopped[:,3]**2) \
+ sum((data_chopped[:,2]-Grand_mean)**2))/sum(data_chopped[:,4]))
```

on selected files. They are different :-(

1) Can anyone explain me what's wrong?

2) Does anyone know a solution to that?

I'll be grateful for help :-)

Cheers,
     PTR

Answer (score 0):

I would say this condition is not passing:
`if filepath == os.path.join(dirname,'GeneralData.dat'):`

which means you are not getting GeneralData.dat before ModelParams.dat. Maybe you need to sort alphabetically or the file is not there.

Comment: Please consider giving my answer the credit by clicking the checkbox next to it :)

Answer (score 0):

I see one issue with the code and the solution that you have provided.

> Never hide the issue of "variable referencing before assignment" by just making the variable visible. 
>    Try to understand why it happened?

Prior to creating a global variable "Grand_mean", you were getting an issue that you are accessing Grand_mean before any value is assigned to it. In such a case, by initializing the variable outside the function and marking it as global, only serves to hide the issue.

You see erroneous result because now you have made the variable visible my making it global but the issue continues to exist. You Grand_mean was never equalized to some correct data.

This means that section of code under "if filepath == os.path.join(dirname,..." was never executed.

Comment: The eyes of the Community at work :-)
Cheers! That was the problem. Fixed!

Comment: @PTR: Cheers. In fact we all learn along the way. I learnt that skipping the issue of prior referencing by global variale make it harder to look at erroneous result.

Answer (score 0):

Using global is not the right solution.  That only makes sense if you do in fact want to reference and assign to the global "Grand_mean" name.  The need for disambiguation comes from the way the interpreter prescans for assignment operators in function declarations.

You should start by assigning a default value to `Grand_mean` within the scope of `LoadGenomeMeanSize()`.  You have 1 of 4 branches to actually assign a value to Grand_mean that has correct semantic meaning within one loop iteration.  You are likely running into a case where

`if filepath == os.path.join(dirname,'ModelParams.dat'):` is true, but either 
`if filepath == os.path.join(dirname,'GeneralData.dat'):` or `if data[-1,4] != 0.0:` is not.  It's likely the second condition that is failing for you. Move the

The quick and dirty answer is you probably need to rearrange your code like this:

```
...
            if filepath == os.path.join(dirname,'GeneralData.dat'):
                data = p.genfromtxt(filepath)
                if data[-1,4] != 0.0: # checking if data set is OK 
                    data_chopped = data[1000:-1,:]  # removing some of data
                    Grand_mean = data_chopped[:,2].mean()
                    Grand_STD = p.sqrt((sum(data_chopped[:,4]*data_chopped[:,3]**2) + sum((data_chopped[:,2]-Grand_mean)**2))/sum(data_chopped[:,4]))

                    if filepath == os.path.join(dirname,'ModelParams.dat'):
                        l = re.split(" ", ln.getline(filepath, 6))
                        turb_param = float(l[2])                
                        arg.append((Grand_mean, Grand_STD, turb_param))
                else:
                    break

...
```

Comment: Nope... then GrandMeansData (the one os.path.walk writes to) is an empty array... 
But if you know that ModelParams.dat always exists when GeneralData.dat exists andvise versa (and that's the case), then you can create a new filepath, let say filepath_two and store information about ModelParams.dat location in it. And that's what I did.

Comment: Reason for that, I belief, is because when condition filepath == os.path.join(dirname,'GeneralData.dat') is true, then (nested in it  ) filepath == os.path.join(dirname,'ModelParams.dat') cannot be true by default and arg.append((Grand_mean, Grand_STD, turb_param)) which fallow does not execute. 

But thanks Jeremy! I tried that anyway :-)